# Sequence Of Zero

Tags: dynamic-programming

Consider the sequence of numbers from 1 to . For example, for  = 9,
we have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Now, place among the numbers one of the three following operators:

```
"+" sum
"-" subtraction
"#" Paste Operator --> paste the previous and the next operands.    
    For example, 1#2 = 12
```

How can I calculate the number of possible sequences that yield zero ?

Example for N = 7:

```
1+2-3+4-5-6+7
1+2-3-4+5+6-7
1-2#3+4+5+6+7
1-2#3-4#5+6#7
1-2+3+4-5+6-7
1-2-3-4-5+6+7
```

See the fourth sequence, it is same as `1-23-45+67` and the result is 0.
All of the above sequences evaluate to zero.

Comment: show the code that you have tried.

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh well ... i have not any code to show ... this is too complicated for me to understand :) ...

Comment: @JJJ any language you wish ... i only want to understand how to solve this ... :)

Comment: Is this from a programming contest/online judge? If yes, can you please provide the link to the original problem statement?

Comment: @MukulGupta surly it is a programming contest,however it don't have direct link to original problem ... i am not so good in English ... and i think there is misunderstanding of this problem ... I'm so sorry that I cannot explain this problem correctly ...

Comment: @AnubhavSingh ...questions ... this function returns bool type ? and exactly what is your main function ? this function call it self again and and again the base case only return 0 or 1 as boolean value ... how this function return all of sequence that i need ... honestly i didn't understand this recursive function ...

Comment: @Amateur-Programmer, this function doesn't return bool type, it return the number of those sequences which evaluate to 0, i.e. an int type.

Comment: As we are counting the number of sequences which evaluates to 0, so the base case is adding 1 to the total count in case a sequence evaluate to 0 else adding 0 to the total count.

Comment: @Amateur-Programmer, I already told you this is just for helping you understand how to approach this problem using dp. It's a recursion, it checks all possible cases.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh ... okay ... and how i can to invoke and use this function in main function  ?
is this true :: 

int main(){
int result =  isEvaluteToZero(7,0,0) ;
}

Comment: @Amateur-Programmer, as far as main function is concerned, it simple. Let me add it for you.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh ...i understand , and i am new in dp programming and this question that i have shared ,is my first dp programming question ... :)

Comment: @AnubhavSingh ... thank you ...  i owe you one ... it surly helps ... i will try to find the dp solution ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recursion based solution just to build your intuition so that you can approach and improve this solution using dynamic programming on your own (implemented in c++):

```
// N is the input
// index_count is the index count in the given sequence
// sum is the total sum of a given sequence
int isEvaluteToZero(int N, int index_count, int sum){
    // if N==1, then the sequence only contains 1 which is not 0, so return 0
    if(N==1){
        return 0;
    }
    // Base case
    // if index_count is equal to N and total sum is 0, return 1, else 0  
    if(index_count==N){
        if(sum==0){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // recursively call by considering '+' between index_count and index_count+1
    // increase index_count by 1
    int placeAdd = isEvaluteToZero(N, index_count+1, sum+index_count+1);
    // recursively call by considering '-' between index_count and index_count+1
    // increase index_count by 1
    int placeMinus = isEvaluteToZero(N, index_count+1, sum-index_count-1);
    // place '#'
    int placePaste;      
    if(index_count+2<=N){
        // paste the previous and the next operands
        // For e.g., (8#9) = 8*(10^1)+9 = 89
        // (9#10) = 9*(10^2)+10 = 910
        // (99#100) = 99*(10^3)+100 = 99100
        // (999#1000) = 999*(10^4)+1000 = 9991000
        int num1 = index_count+1;
        int num2 = index_count+2;
        int concat_num = num1*(int)(pow(10, (int)num2/10 + 1) + 0.5)+num2;
        placePaste = isEvaluteToZero(N, index_count+2, sum+concat_num) + isEvaluteToZero(N, index_count+2, sum-concat_num);
    }else{
        // in case index_count+2>N
        placePaste = 0;
    }
    return (placeAdd+placeMinus+placePaste);
}
int main(){
    int N, res=1, index_count=1;
    cout<<"Enter N:";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<isEvaluteToZero(N, index_count, res)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
N=1 output=0
N=2 output=0
N=3 output=1
N=4 output=1
N=7 output=6
```